# Upload file option not shown in trumbowyg wysiwyg editor

Tags: laravel-5.1, wysiwyg, trumbowyg

I am using trumbowyg wysiwyg editor in my laravel app. In the editor, upload option is not show though upload plugin is already installed.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure you include a few things when you call the plugin.

```
btns: ['viewHTML',
       '|', 'formatting',
       '|', 'btnGrp-design',
       '|', 'link',
       '|', 'image',
       '|', 'btnGrp-justify',
       '|', 'btnGrp-lists',
       '|', 'horizontalRule']
```

You also need to customise the image button to contain the dropdown

```
btnsDef: {
                // Customizables dropdowns
                image: {
                    dropdown: ['insertImage', 'upload', 'base64'],
                    ico: 'insertImage'
                }
         },
```

My example in full below

```
$('textarea').trumbowyg({
            autogrow: true,
            fullscreenable: false,
            btnsDef: {
                // Customizables dropdowns
                image: {
                    dropdown: ['insertImage', 'upload', 'base64'],
                    ico: 'insertImage'
                }
            },
            btns: ['viewHTML',
                '|', 'formatting',
                '|', 'btnGrp-design',
                '|', 'link',
                '|', 'image',
                '|', 'btnGrp-justify',
                '|', 'btnGrp-lists',
                '|', 'horizontalRule']
        });
```